# Templates text box in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, comments

I use text boxes to comment on pdfs, and there are abut 50 comments that I reuse often with minor changes. Currently, I am just copying the text from a word file, and pasting it a text box in the pdf. Is there a way to maintain a list of comment text boxes from inside Acrobat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Auto-Complete features under Preferences > Forms should help.

[image: Adobe Acrobat properties with Auto-Complete feature highlighted]